# Using Azure Active Directory on Azure Web App with Meteor

Tags: azure, meteor, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am creating a Meteor App and am going through the process of deploying through Azure Web App services. I am using the azure-demeteorizer package in order to do so and am not running into any troubles there. I am also using the accounts-azure-active-directory package to enable users within my organization the ability to login to the application.

All of this currently works on localhost, but when I upload to my Web App I get to the login page and when I click login the screen just goes white and doesn't sign me in.

Below are a couple screenshots of the process I am describing.

[Clicking the 'sign in' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyHuT.png)

[White Screen after signing in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajx4F.png)

EDIT:

I have enabled the permissions to sign in on my web app (cannot post another picture due to not enough reputation). imgur.com/nXzPo59 (permissions picture)

Comment: Did you add the redirect URI for the Webapp deployment? What is the web request and response that result in the blank page? Can you use your browsers developer tools to get that info?

Comment: @Saca would that be something I set up through Azure Active Directory?

Comment: Redirect URI, yes, in the configure tab for the application. Also have to maje sure the meteor app is sending the right value, thus my ask for the request/response to check.

Comment: @Saca I don't see anything called "Redirect URI", so maybe that is the cause. I have my APP ID URI set, but I am not sure if that is what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, "Reply URL"

Comment: @Saca Yes, I have those set to `www.myurl.com/_oauth/azureAd?close` and `www.myurl.com/_oauth/azureAd` since that is what is specified in the package I am using.

Comment: Saw your comment in MSDN forums, you're getting a 404 on your /_oauth/azureAd?code=<somelongstring>. So Azure AD is redirecting you to the place you told it to, but you're telling it to go to a page that doesn't exist. There must be something wrong with your setup of Meteor which is resulting in it not listening at www.myurl.com/_oauth/azureAd. Can you confirm that you don't get a 404 when you navigate to that URL via your browser directly?

Comment: @Saca Thanks for the response, this is what I get when I visit that site from my browser (http://imgur.com/UC04clf). When I click the close window nothing happens. Not sure if that detail is important or not.

Comment: Are the two URLs identical? Both have https and all?

Comment: As far as I know... `https://webapp.azurewebsites.net/_oauth/azureAd` `https://webapp.azurewebsites.net/_oauth/azureAd?code=<somestring>`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after going back and forth with the Microsoft NodeJS team we found the issue and the solution.

The issue was that OAuth2.0 + Web App + Active Directory creates some sort of limit on url strings where that limit is 1024 characters. Sometimes your app's authentication token will cause the url to exceed this limit giving you this mysterious 404 error.

The solution for this is to navigate to your KUDU console and go to site>wwwroot>web.config and edit that. Add the missing line `<requestLimits maxQueryString="20000"/>` inside the `<requestFiltering>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add you app to your azure active directory , then give it the acces

Comment: I think I have already done that and I just edited my post with a imgur link to that.